# file size not shown before download start

Tags: php, header, download, filesize

Here is my code in php :
[image: sample demo capture]
**Download worked but file size not showed size **

```
$infofile="sample.rar";
header("Content-Description:File Transfer");
header("Content-Type:application/x-rar");
header("Content-Lenght:".(string)filesize($infofile));
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=sample_filename_for_dowload.rar");
header("Expires:0");
header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre=check=0");
header("Progma:public");
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($infofile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because of your typo

Content-lenght

Should be Content-Length
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html